# Chisel how to test only one package

Tags: chisel

I am working with [chisel-template](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel-template)

In my `src/main/scala` I have two folders, let say A and B.

In `src/test/scala`, I have a folder for A and a folder for B.

I want to test only A but when I do

```
$ sbt "test:runMain A.TestMain"
```

I have the errors of B which make the compilation fail. I know there are problems in B but I just want to check A first.

How can I test or compile only one folder ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this. But if you use scalatest to launch your tests instead of a main it's fairly easy.
You can specify just the path you want with `testOnly` for example, from sbt command line

```
testOnly A.*
```

Or from the shell command line

```
sbt 'testOnly A.*'
```

In fact, with tests you can even specify specific tests within a test harness by using

```
sbt 'testOnly A.* -- -z "dog"'
```

(notes, the quoting is significant), 
you can run only those tests in package a that have the word dog in the test name

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner of scala, so there may be better ways.

[sbt ReferenceManual](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html) tells us to add statement like below in build.sbt

```
excludeFilter in unmanagedSources := "excludedFileName"
```

If you want to exclude files only when running test, you can specify it like below.

```
excludeFilter in (Test, unmanagedSources) := "excludedFileName"
```

Probably, your question is about sbt, not chisel. That's why you may get better and more detailed answer if you add `scala` tag.